# How can I execute concurrent 10000K thread in jmeter during performance test?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Is that possible to execute 10000 concurrent user in jmeter?

If so how?

What should be the ram-up time for this scenario??

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's limit of virtual users per [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is very high, to be precise it's [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647)

The question is: do you have good enough hardware to simulate 10 000 users from a single machine. The process of checking it looks as follows:

1. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Set up monitoring of the CPU, RAM, Network, Swap, Disk usage on JMeter side, it can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
3. Start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load at the same time looking into CPU, RAM, etc. usage. Here there could be 2 options:

   - you will be able to reach 10 000 users without issues, if this is the case you should be good to go
   - you will run out of resources earlier, in this case look into i.e. [Active Threads Over Time listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) to see how many users you were able to simulate from this machine and extrapolate the value to determine how many load generators you will need for 10 000 users using [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) approach

There is no golden rule for ramp-up time calculation, the good practice is to onboard the users gradually, this way you will be able to correlate increasing load with increasing response time, increasing number of errors, etc. Adding 3 users each second so in 1 hour you will have 10 000 seems a valid starting point to me.